# Mostrar valor que tenga el mismo valor que otro

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

me explico. Tengo una tabla que se llama Empleados. Quiero mostrar los datos de los empleados que pertenezcan al mismo departamento que 'Jorge', pero no he podido hacerlo. He intentado comandos de subconsulta pero siempre me marca error, como este:

`select * from empleados where dept_no = (select * from empleados where apellido = 'Jorge');`

¿Alguien sabe como se podría hacer algo así con subconsultas? Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes comparar una columna, dept_no, con varias,*.
Debería ser

```
select * from empleados where dept_no = (select dept_no from empleados where apellido = 'Jorge');
```

Comment: Ahi funcionó! Gracias!